# Error converting date in sql server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I get this error when I run the following code:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

```
Declare @t date
Set @t = DATEADD(DAY, -75, GETDATE())

Select * from
(
SELECT changeField,  CONVERT(date, newValue) newDate, changeDateTime, pubId, changeType, @t today
      FROM ChangeLog
      WHERE ISDATE(newValue) = 1 
) dates
where newDate < today
```

If I comment out `where newDate < today`, it works.  There should not be any conversion in the where clause.

Comment: The `CONVERT(date, newValue)` can happen before rows are filtered out by the `WHERE` clause. You can use `TRY_CONVERT` if 2012+ or else need to do `CONVERT(date, CASE WHEN ISDATE(newValue) = 1 THEN newValue END)`

Comment: CONVERT(date, CASE WHEN ISDATE(newValue) = 1 THEN newValue END) solved the problem. It was evaluating the outer where clause before the subquery.